# Linking error with Boost.python while compiling

Tags: c++, makefile, boost-python

Am trying to build the example inspired from [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/python/doc/html/article.htm)

My original intention is to be able to call C++ code from within Python. I'm just running the examples from the Boost documentation in order to achieve this goal.

Here's my makefile

```
CXX               := g++
CXX_FLAGS         := -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -ggdb

BIN               := bin
SRC               := src
INCLUDE           := inc
LIB               := lib

BOOST_ROOT        := /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install
BOOST_INCL        := ${BOOST_ROOT}/include/
BOOST_LIBS        := ${BOOST_ROOT}/libs/ 

PYTHON_INCL       := /usr/include/python3.7m/
PYTHON_LIBS       := /usr/lib/python3.7/

LIBFLAGS          := -lboost_system 
EXECUTABLE        := greet


all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all
        clear
        ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp 
        $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -I$(PYTHON_INCL) -I$(INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INCL) -L$(BOOST_LIBS) -L$(PYTHON_LIBS) -L$(LIB$

clean:
        -rm $(BIN)/*
```

This leads to the following errors

> /tmp/ccNVjFX3.o: In function `boost::python::api::object::object()':
>   /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:400:
>   undefined reference to`_Py_NoneStruct' /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function
>   `PyInit_hello_ext':
>   /home/eicossa/Dropbox/wtcd/license/boost/src/bindings.cpp:3: undefined
>   reference to`boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void
>   (*)())' /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function `boost::python::type_info::name()
>   const':
>   /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/type_id.hpp:160:
>   undefined reference to`boost::python::detail::gcc_demangle(char
>   const*)' /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function
>   `boost::python::to_python_value<char const* const&>::operator()(char
>   const* const&) const':
>   /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/converter/builtin_converters.hpp:157:
>   undefined reference to`
>   boost::python::converter::do_return_to_python(char const*)'
>   /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function `boost::python::to_python_value<char
>   const* const&>::get_pytype() const':
>   /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/converter/builtin_converters.hpp:157:
>   undefined reference to`PyUnicode_Type' /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function
>   `void boost::python::def<char const* (*)()>(char const*, char const*
>   (*)())':
>   /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/def.hpp:91:
>   undefined reference to`boost::python::detail::scope_setattr_doc(char
>   const*, boost::python::api::object const&, char const*)'
>   /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function `boost::python::api::object
>   boost::python::detail::make_function_aux
>
> > (char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies const&, boost::mpl::vector1 const&)':
> >     /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/make_function.hpp:38:
> >     undefined reference to
> >     `boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function
> >     const&)' /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function`
> >     boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::py_function_impl_base()':
> >     /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:20:
> >     undefined reference to `vtable for
> >     boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base'
> >     /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFPKcvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IS6_EEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFPKcvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IS6_EEEEEE]+0x30):
> >     undefined reference to`
> >     boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::max_arity() const'
> >     /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In function
> >     `boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<boost::python::detail::caller<char
> >     const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies,
> >     boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> > >::~caller_py_function_impl()':
> >     /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:30:
> >     undefined reference to`
> >     boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::~py_function_impl_base()'
> >     /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFPKcvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IS6_EEEEEE[_ZTIN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFPKcvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IS6_EEEEEE]+0x10):
> >     undefined reference to `typeinfo for
> >     boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base' /tmp/ccQNpbxG.o: In
> >     function`boost::python::converter::expected_pytype_for_arg::get_pytype()':
> >     /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:69:
> >     undefined reference to
> >     `boost::python::converter::registry::query(boost::python::type_info)'
> >     /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install/include/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:70:
> >     undefined reference to`
> >     boost::python::converter::registration::expected_from_python_type()
> >     const' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:27: recipe
> >     for target 'bin/greet' failed make: *** [bin/greet] Error 1

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

```
CXX               := g++
CXX_FLAGS         := -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -ggdb

BIN               := bin
SRC               := src
INCLUDE           := inc
LIB               := lib

BOOST_ROOT        := /home/eicossa/repo/boost_install
BOOST_INCL        := ${BOOST_ROOT}/include/
BOOST_LIBS        := ${BOOST_ROOT}/libs/ 

PYTHON_INCL       := /usr/include/python3.7m/
PYTHON_LIBS       := /usr/lib/python3.7/

LIBFLAGS          := -lboost_system  -lboost_python37 -lpython3.7m #changes made here
EXECUTABLE        := greet


all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all
        clear
        ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp 
        $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -I$(PYTHON_INCL) -I$(INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INCL) -L$(BOOST_LIBS) -L$(PYTHON_LIBS) -L$(LIB$

clean:
        -rm $(BIN)/*
```

Try out these changes in the Makefile